# Calculation based on mapping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - Table1. Items with volume. and Table2. Mapping table.
Table1. Items with volume.

```
Item   |  Small  | Medium  |  Large  |  XLarge|  Volume  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------   
Shirt  |---10----|----0----|---20----|---0----|-----------  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------  
Pants  |----0----|----30---|---10----|---20---|-----------  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------  
Skirts |----0----|----30---|---10----|---20---|-----------  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------
```

Table 2. Mapping table

```
Item  |Size  
------|-------  
Shirt |small  
------|-------  
Shirt |medium  
------|-------   
Shirt |large  
------|-------  
Pants |large  
------|-------  
Skirts|medium
```

I need to calculate Volume in the Table 1 using mapping. For example,
for Shirt I look at the mapping table and see that we have small, medium and large sizes. So I need to summarize Small, Medium and Large columns from Table 1 for ALL ITEMS (not just for shirt) which would be 110.

Output table:

```
Item   |  Small  | Medium  |  Large  |  XLarge|  Volume  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------   
Shirt  |---10----|----0----|---20----|---0----|----110----  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------  
Pants  |----0----|----30---|---10----|---20---|-----40----  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------  
Skirts |----0----|----30---|---10----|---20---|-----60----  
-------|---------|---------|---------|--------|-----------

select step1.Item
from 
(select t1.Item
,t1.Small
,t1.Medium
,t1.Large
from t1) step1
full outer join
t2
on t1.Item=t2.Item
group by t1.Item
,t1.Small
,t1.Medium
,t1.Large
```

Can't figure out the case statement. Please help!

Comment: Katie, you can use <pre> and </pre> tags around your tables to use a fixed width font. This will make them much more legible.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @CraigYoung thank you!

Comment: Katie you need to double-check your example. I cannot see how you get to 100 using Small, Medium and Large.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen to have in the Volume column calculated volumes for Shirt (110), Pants (40) and Skirts (60)

Comment: No...show us the output as a table

Comment: @CraigYoung thanks! it is 110

Comment: @CraigYoung I had to replace real names by "shirt", "pants" and "skirts" but in real situation for Shirt I need to sum Shirt Small+Shirt Medium+Shirt Large+Pants Small+Pants Medium+Pants Large+Skirt Small+Skirt Medium+Skirt Large. . For Pants sum of Shirt Large+Pants Large+Skirt Large. For Skirt sum of Shirt Medium+Pants Medium+Skirt Medium.

Answer (score 0):

Because your requirement is to "summarise (specific sizes) from Table 1 for ALL ITEMS", it's beneficial to get the totals per size off the bat. A simple summation query (`select sum(Small) as Small, sum(Medium)...`) will be included as a sub-query in the final solution so that the per-size totals can be easily "looked up".

In order to calculate the Volume per Item, we need to pivot the Mapping table so that there is one row per item, and we can sum the size totals for each mapped size. Use a `cross join` to the totals above, and a `case` statement to transform `Mapping.Size` values into the corresponding total value.

As a final step select from `Table1` to get the source Items with Size specific volumes; and join to the above as a sub-query to get the corresponding total volumes.

The query below uses SQL Server table variables to demonstrate using your sample data. You can replace with an appropriate mysql equivalent to confirm.

```
declare @Table1 table (
   Item varchar(10),
   Small int, Medium int, Large int, XLarge int)
insert into @Table1 values
('Shirt', 10, 0, 20, 0),
('Pants', 0, 30, 10, 20),
('Skirts', 0, 30, 10, 20)

declare @Mapping table(
   Item varchar(10),
   Size varchar(10))
insert into @Mapping values
('Shirt', 'small'),
('Shirt', 'med'),
('Shirt', 'large'),
('Pants', 'large'),
('Skirts', 'med')

select  a.*, v.Volume
from    @Table1 a
        /* Join main table back to mapping based summary for final result */
        left join (
        /* The following is a "manual pivot" technique used to 
           transform rows into aggregated columns. */
        select  m.Item,
                /* Aggregate totals accoring to the mapping */
                sum(
                case m.Size
                    when 'large' then t.Large
                    when 'med' then t.Medium
                    when 'small' then t.Small
                    when 'xlarge' then t.XLarge
                    else 0
                end
                ) Volume
        from    @Mapping m
                cross join (
                     /* Get totals of each column */
                     select  sum(Small) Small,
                             sum(Medium) Medium, 
                             sum(Large) Large, 
                             sum(XLarge) XLarge
                     from    @table1
                ) t
        group by m.Item
        ) v on v.Item = a.Item
```

Comment: @Katie There are multiple instances of "Large"; knowing which one the error message is referring to goes a long way to figuring out "why". Often such an error indicates a missing or misplaced comma/equal sign/bracket etc. But more importantly, as I pointed out in the answer, you cannot use this directly in mysql (_it's a SQL Server query and works as is on 2008 R2 or above_). However, the query itself is standard SQL not using any advanced features. It should work on most platforms after substituting the table names appropriately.